# How to upgrade Kubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

Sorry this is a really basic question. I've only been using Kubuntu for a week or two, and a lot of it is unfamiliar to me still. I did a search, and tried things like `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and `sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop`, but nothing I've tried has worked.... and I suspect it shouldn't be that hard.

I'm used to using a system that automatically updates itself every day, so it is bizarre to me that I can't even update manually without putting some effort in to it. What's going on here?

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:        20.10
Codename:       groovy
```

`

Comment: Yes, I suppose so, I'm just trying to update my system. When I go to https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/, it says the latest version is 21.04. In particular, there are a couple of KDE bugs that have been fixed in the newer versions.

Comment: The duplicate link @user535733 deals with the specific reason why you can't upgrade yet to 21.04 (from 20.10) which should answer your question I'd hope fully... but if you need more you can follow the link to the question it was marked duplicate to (as Rik Mills the person who answered that question is a Kubuntu developer; his answer was for a prior cycle but you'll understand by now hopefully; delays are to ensure you system is as *stable* as possible)

Comment: Thanks, I read those links you provided. Is it standard for them to release the image for download, but not as an update? That strikes me as odd, so perhaps this particular situation may have more to do with the shim bug mentioned in the other answer. I get what you mean about delays helping the system be stable, but that's also how I ended up in this situation still being impacted by bugs fixed 4 months ago... so, there's pros and cons both ways.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2021-April/041448.html) may have something to do with why you are not receiving the upgrade:

> In case you missed it in the release notes[[1]](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-notes/19221#heading-release-upgrades) and hear people asking
> about it, I wanted to let you know that users of Ubuntu 20.10 are not
> being prompted to upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04. Subsequently, upgrading to
> Ubuntu 21.04 still requires running do-release-upgrade with the '-d'
> switch. This is due to a bug[[2]](http://launchpad.net/bugs/1925010) with the current version of shim in
> Ubuntu 21.04 which can cause systems with an early version of EFI to
> fail to boot after the upgrade. Due to the severity of the issue we
> shouldn't be encouraging people to upgrade at this point in time.
>
> After we have a new version of shim signed will make it available in
> Ubuntu 21.04 and then enable upgrades.

Comment: Thanks, I subbed to the bug so I can keep an eye on things!